# Question about get line and string find function

Tags: c++

I new to c++. I am trying to remove some words from each line of a text. But, if the word cannot be found, it returns 4294967295 instead of -1. Does anyone encounter same situation? 
First, I use "getline" from the text.txt

```
  while(getline(fintext,line)){
...
  }
```

Then I use

```
while (line.find(word) != -1){
   line.erase(line.find(word),word.length()-1);
   line.find(word);
```

it doesn't work.

```
while (line.find(word) != 4294967295){
   line.erase(line.find(word),word.length()-1);
   line.find(word);
```

it works now. But I do not understand and how can I fix it. Thank You.

Comment: In many cases 4294967295 IS -1. They can both be encoded in binary as 11111111111111111111111111111111. What matters is how you look at the that sequence of bits.

Comment: I'd also wager that if you turned warnings on, you'd get a signed-unsigned comparison warning that would tip you off about this.

Comment: What source are you learning from that says to use -1 instead of `std::string::npos`? It's wrong whatever it is.

Comment: Using `-1` makes some logical sense and is used in some other languages (e.g. Python). I used it a lot when I started C++... that was until I found out about `string::npos`. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::string::npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos).

```
while (line.find(word) != std::string::npos) {
   // ...
}
```

The key points from [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) which fail your loop-condition are:

> Although the definition uses `-1`, `size_type` is an unsigned integer type, and the value of `npos` is the largest positive value it can hold, due to [signed-to-unsigned implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions). This is a portable way to specify the largest value of any unsigned type.

Hard-coding `-1`, `4294967295`, or any other constant is not reliable across different implementations.

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos)

> Although the definition uses -1, `size_type` is an unsigned integer type, and the value of npos is the largest positive value it can hold, due to signed-to-unsigned implicit conversion. This is a portable way to specify the largest value of any unsigned type.

So you should use `std::string::npos`, not rely on the magic number -1.

Comment: Using npos is also a good practice in that you can look quickly through your project for all references to it. Having distinguishable end condition returns for your functions is really important for readability. Otherwise, you might get a -1 return confused for a function which may return it totally legitimately.